# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm developing an Android app which reads data from MySQL database and I faced this error. I have this XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" > 


        <TextView android:id="@+id/wardNumber" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
            android:text="Ward Number" 
            android:textSize="22dp"/> 


        <TextView android:id="@+id/dateTime" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@id/wardNumber" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp" 
            android:text="Date-Time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/dateTime"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateTime"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wardNumber"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
            android:text="Name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the my Java file:

```
public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);            
    }

    Application app = items.get(position);

    if(app != null) {
      //  ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
        TextView wardNumber = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.wardNumber);
        TextView name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
      //  LinearLayout ratingCntr = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ratingCntr);
        TextView dateTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);

  //      if(icon != null) {
  //          Resources res = getContext().getResources();
   //         String sIcon = "com.sj.jsondemo:drawable/" + app.getIcon();
   //         icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(sIcon, null, null)));
   //     }

        if(wardNumber != null) wardNumber.setText(app.getTitle());

        if(name != null) name.setText(app.getTitle());

        if(dateTime != null) {
            dateTime.setText(app.getTotalDl());
          //  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
          //  dateTime.setText(nf.format(app.getTotalDl())+" dl");            
        }


    }

    return v;
}
}
```

When this Activity is called, I receive this error message:

```
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2863)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at com.sj.jsondemo.Appl icationAdapter.getView(ApplicationAdapter.java:53)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:701)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:311)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
11-24 21:12:03.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at  android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 21:12:03.633:  E/AndroidRuntime(1251):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 21:12:08.922: I/Process(1251): Sending signal. PID: 1251 SIG: 9
```

I don't know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 498, accepted):

Change

```
dateTime.setText(app.getTotalDl());
```

To

```
dateTime.setText(String.valueOf(app.getTotalDl()));
```

There are different versions of `setText` - one takes a String and one takes an int resource id. If you pass it an integer it will try to look for the corresponding string resource id - which it can't find, which is your error.

I guess `app.getTotalDl()` returns an int. You need to specifically tell `setText` to set it to the String value of this int.

[setText (int resid)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) vs  [setText (CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: setText(int resId) doesn't even have javadoc attached to it. They should really have given that one a separate name -- obviously a common misuse here.

So, specifying the resId sets a TextView's text to be the text of another resource?

Comment: I already know this, but I always forget this and always end up on this answer

Answer (score 15):

Replace

```
dateTime.setText(app.getTotalDl());
```

With

```
dateTime.setText(""+app.getTotalDl());
```

Comment: It is work, But I think It is not suitable way.  @KenWolf answer is The correct and Professional way.

Answer (score 2):

If we get the value as `int` and we set it to `String`, the error occurs. PFB my solution,

```
Textview = tv_property_count;
int property_id;
tv_property_count.setText(String.valueOf(property_id));
```

Answer (score 2):

if you get the values in int you have to use string for that it is throwing the error

before

```
  holder.villageName.setText(villageModelList.get(position).getVillageName());
    holder.villageCount.setText(villageModelList.get(position).getPeopleCount());
    holder.peopleCount.setText(villageModelList.get(position).getPeopleCount());
```

after

```
  holder.villageName.setText(villageModelList.get(position).getVillageName());
    holder.villageCount.setText(String.valueOf(villageModelList.get(position).getPeopleCount()));
    holder.peopleCount.setText(String.valueOf(villageModelList.get(position).getPeopleCount()));
```

you can solve the error by adding the **String.valueOf**

Answer (score 1):

When you try to set text in `Edittext` or `textview` you
should pass only String format.

```
dateTime.setText(app.getTotalDl());
```

to

```
dateTime.setText(String.valueOf(app.getTotalDl()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin

```
dateTime.setText(
    app.getTotalDl().toString()
)
```

If the problem persists and you are using `data binding` in case, please recheck your `android:text` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluated value for settext was integer so it went to see a resource attached to it but it was not found, you wanted to set text so it should be string so convert integer into string by attaching `.toStringe`  or `String.valueOf(int)` will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. this is a easy way.

```
txtTopicNo.setText(10+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dateTime.setText(String.valueOf(app.getTotalDl()));
```

or

```
dateTime.setText(app.getTotalDl() + "");
```

When the data is not String