# Cant use OnClickListener in Custom Layout in Android?

Tags: java, android

So I made my own LinearLayout because I needed a horizontal number picker. I am using this custom layout twice in my activity:

[image]

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_minus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lt"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_plus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gt"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public class NumberPickerHorizontal extends LinearLayout
{
    private final EditText number;
    private final Button button_minus, button_plus;

    public NumberPickerHorizontal(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.numberpicker_horizontal, this, true);

        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

        button_minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_minus);
        button_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int count = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                number.setText(count--);
            }
        });

        button_plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_plus);
        button_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int count = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                number.setText(count++);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You'll notice I'm trying to activate the onClick methods for the plus and minus buttons... However, when I actually click the buttons, I get the following error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177003/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x0)

Comment: That does supress the error... but the text of the number field doesnt change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to `setText` for 0, which should be an string resource(int).
Also your new increased value is never used. Increase count before setting the text. Then use `setText(String.valueOf(increased count value))`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_minus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lt"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_plus"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gt"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</merge>
```

Java:

```
public class NumberPickerHorizontal extends LinearLayout
{
    private final EditText number;
    private final Button button_minus, button_plus;

    @Override
    public NumberPickerHorizontal(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public NumberPickerHorizontal(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public NumberPickerHorizontal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    @Override
    public NumberPickerHorizontal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
    //android:layout_width="match_parent"
    //android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    //set these where you instantiate the view, XML or code!

        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.numberpicker_horizontal, this, true);

            number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

            button_minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_minus);
            button_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int count = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                    count--;
                    number.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            });

            button_plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_plus);
            button_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int count = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                    count++;
                    number.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            });
    }
```

So the changes were:

1.) added `<merge>` to remove the duplicate layout

2.) added the remaining 3 constructors for the view in case the framework calls them

3.) added `String.valueOf()` around your `int` so that it's not perceived as a resource identifier by `setText()`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue: `number.setText(count++)` is still wrong. But using `<merge>` is a good pointer to improvements.

Comment: @tynn you're right, I added the relevant fix too. At first glance I figured the wrong constructor is called nad that's why the clicks don't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.numberpicker_horizontal, this, true);
```

And replace all `findViewById` by `v.findViewById`