# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource id #0x64

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I make an app with background services and broadcast receiver, and my app consists of a `MainActivity.java` and `myServiceRunner.java`. When I start the background service, it gives me this error, `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource id #0x64`.

I put these codes inside   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState):

```
     IntentFilter mainFilter=new IntentFilter("liren.action.GOSERVICE3");
      receiver=new MyMainLocalReceiver();
      registerReceiver(receiver, mainFilter);
```

> MyMainLocalReceiver.java

```
   public class MyMainLocalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try
        {
            int serviceData=intent.getIntExtra("serviceData",0);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serviceData,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            tvStepsCount.setText(serviceData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tvStepsCount.setText(e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Inside myServiceRunner extends Service class, I have added these codes inside onStartCommand method.

```
  @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Thread triggerService=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(;;)
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent myFilteredResponse = new Intent("liren.action.GOSERVICE3");
                    myFilteredResponse.putExtra("serviceData",100);
                    sendBroadcast(myFilteredResponse);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    triggerService.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

> manifest.xml

I have added these:

```
    <service android:name=".myServiceRunner"></service>
    <receiver android:name=".RecordSaved$MyMainLocalReceiver"></receiver>
```

I could not figure out the error, can anyone help me please? Thanks :)

Comment: try  tvStepsCount.setText(""+serviceData);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177003/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x0)

Comment: thanks so much @Sathish Kumar J, it works :)

Comment: @Antoni kindly accept my answer. then only others can easily find correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `.SetText()`. but you are passing `int` type. that's a problem. so you need to convert your `int to String`

Try like,

```
tvStepsCount.setText("" + serviceData); // concat with empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the TextView class, first argument to TextView.setText() method can be either a resId, ie an integer or char sequence or char array. Therefore android studio will not show error or warning while you pass an Integer value to TexView.setText().

In your code `tvStepsCount.setText(serviceData);` serviceData is an integer type, android treat this value as a *resId* and look for the corresponding resource in R class. Since serviceData is not a resId actually android return *Resources$NotFoundException*.

So in this case we need to explicitly convert serviceData to *String* type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
 tvStepsCount.setText(String.valueOf(serviceData));
```