# How can i dynamically change my TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-ion

All the methods are invoked in MainActivity.
In my app i'm getting an HTML page from ion library and i have some methods for format the text i've downloaded with ion.

That what i'm trying to do is to set variable `DoveSono` in a TextView, actually at every cycle of the loop that variable changes so the TextView should change too but actually with what i've done the app crash.

This is the method that i invoke onClick and start ion with getting the HTML website then it invoke other methods:

```
       private void getHTMLArticoli(){

   //     progressDialog = new SpotsDialog(articoli.this, R.style.Custom);
   //     progressDialog.show();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                htmlresultart = null;
                try {
                    htmlresultart = Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load("WEBSITEIP")
                            .asString()
                            .get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (htmlresultart != null) {
                    htmlresultart = htmlresultart.replace("</td>", "\n");
                    getTableArticoli();
                    getTestataArticoli();
                    getBodyArticoli();

      //              progressDialog.cancel();
                }
```

While here is the method getBodyArticoli that i calls in getHTMLArticoli here you can find the part where i'm trying to setText

```
    private void getBodyArticoli(){

        DaDoveParto = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(htmlresultart.indexOf("TBLCRP")));
        DoveMiFermo = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(htmlresultart.indexOf("</form>")));

        if(DaDoveParto == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this,"NESSUN DATO TROVATO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            Integer i;
            Integer j;
            Integer CONTACAMPO = 0;
            for( i = DaDoveParto ; i <= DoveMiFermo ; i++){
                if( htmlresultart.substring(i, i + 4).equals("<td>")){
                    i += 4;
                    for (j = i; j <= DoveMiFermo ; j++){
                        if(htmlresultart.substring(j, j + 1).equals("\n")){

                            appBODYart[CONTACAMPO] = htmlresultart.substring(i, i + (j - i));

                            if(appBODYart[CONTACAMPO].equals("(null)")){
                                appBODYart[CONTACAMPO] = "";
                            }
                            CONTACAMPO += 1;

                            if(CONTACAMPO.equals(QuantiCampi)){
                                CONTACAMPO = 0;
                                myDB.insertArtServer(appBODYart[0], appBODYart[1], appBODYart[2], appBODYart[3], appBODYart[4], appBODYart[5],
                                        appBODYart[6], appBODYart[7], appBODYart[8]);

                                DoveSono +=0;
                                textView.setText(String.valueOf(DoveSono);
                            }
                            break;
```

Actually when i'm trying to do it i'm getting the following error:

> 05-31 17:24:41.515 4605-4769/com.example.igardini.visualposmobile
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
>       Process: com.example.igardini.visualposmobile, PID: 4605
>       android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6363)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:874)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3112)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17484)
>           at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6932)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4083)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3941)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3916)
>           at com.example.igardini.visualposmobile.articoli.getBodyArticoli(articoli.java:121)
>           at com.example.igardini.visualposmobile.articoli.access$300(articoli.java:17)
>           at com.example.igardini.visualposmobile.articoli$2.run(articoli.java:79)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: `textView.setText(String.valueOf(DoveSono))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177003/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x0)

Comment: It's not so easy also with String.valueOf i'm getting 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'

Comment: [Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi).

Comment: I know that i could use runnable but i don't getting how to implement it in my method getBodyArticoli ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to wrap the

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(DoveSono * 100 / QuanteRighe));
```

with

```
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        textView.setText(String.valueOf(DoveSono * 100 / QuanteRighe));

                                    }
                                });
```